# How do I generate mipmap images in OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

What is the equivalent function of `gluBuild2DMipmaps()` in OpenGL ES on an iPhone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

glGenerateMipmapOES(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

document
http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/glGenerateMipmap.xml